# Can't Load my Assets when running my java AWT game jar by RightClicking on MacOS

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, embedded-resource

i made a game with awt and made a jar out of it . but when i run it by right clicking it it doesnt load the assets ( assets are on the jar file) **But** then i run it with terminal it loads the assets !

i'm using **MacOS Monterey** and **Java 17**

i used this code to get a image :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Image {
    public BufferedImage image;
    public Image(String Path){
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(Path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        this.image = img;
    }
    public static void drawImage(Graphics2D g,Image image,int x,int y,int w,int h){
        g.drawImage(image.image,x,y,w,h,null);
    }
}
```

and i called them like this:

```
Image image = new Image("Data/image.PNG");

// And in my draw Method:
public void draw(Graphics2D g){
        Image.drawImage(g,image,0,0,32,32);

}
```

the game with double clicking the jar on mac
[game with double clicking(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZhWr.png)

and the game with opening the game with : (**java -jar game.jar**)
[game with running on terminal(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J55Q.png)

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources:
https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans
https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse

Comment: See: [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource).

Comment: im using a game loop and i think this method not going to work with a gameloop

Comment: Loading images has nothing to do with a game loop. The issue is finding the image to load from your jar file. Also, images should be preloaded once to make the game fast and efficient.

Comment: Jar entries are not separate files.  You will **never** be able to read a .jar entry using File.  Game loops have nothing to do with it.  This is literally what the Class.getResource method is for.